# Google drive api - check if file is public?

Tags: php, api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to hook an app up to google drive and I've got everything working, I'm just having trouble checking the file permissions. Right now I'm getting back a bunch of files and I want to filter them so it only shows the publicly available ones. How do I go about doing this? If I run `$file->getShared()` or `$file->getPermissions()` they both return null regardless of if the file is private or public.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make sure that your $file object contains all properties, especially permissions. Do this with `fields => *` when you fetch the file.

Then iterate the permissions array to see if there is a permission with `type = anyone`